# Compatibility of tyres with wheelset

Tags: wheels, tyre-width

I have a E13 TRS, 28 holes, tubeless ready, 30 mm inner width wheelset, with [SCHWALBE MAGIC MARY, 29 x 2.35, Addix Soft](https://www.schwalbe.com/en/offroad-reader/hans-dampf.html), front and a SCHWALBE NEW HANS DAMPF, 29 x 2.35, Addix Soft, rear. (The bike is [here](https://www.commencal-store.co.uk/meta-am-29-signature-2019-c2x26307414).) I am not sure but Is the wheelset (and frame) compatible with the same tyres in the 2.60 width version ? What could be the impacts of such a change ? Comparing on Schwalbe's website lead to less road and off-road grip and more rolling. Is this really true ? What else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [technical specifications page](https://www.commencal-store.co.uk/meta-am-29-signature-2019-c2x26307414) for your bicycle:

> **MAXIMUM TYRE DIMENSION (ETRTO)   70 mm**

70 mm is 2.75 inches, so a 2.60 tyre should fit.

Tyre sizes are notoriously imprecise, but a 2.60 should be significantly smaller than a 2.75.

You can be as certain as you can be that it will fit, especially as you're sticking with not only the same manufacturer but the same model.

The impact of a larger tyre?  A "softer" ride - you'll be better able to absorb bumps and roll over smaller obstacles, at the likely cost of some precision in control and perhaps a slightly increased rolling resistance.